# Angular 2 DI, use a custom Http

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a service that uses Http:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class OrdersService {
    constructor(@Inject(Http) private http:Http) {}
    ...
}
```

And a component that uses it

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';

import { OrdersService } from '../services/orders.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  providers: [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS, //{ provide: Http, useClass: Http }
      AuthService, AuthStore,
      OrdersService
  ]
})
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private ordersService: OrdersService){}
      ....
}
```

This works. I have some commented out text { provide: Http, useClass: Http }. I want to provide my own class here that extends Http, but still has all the same dependancies. The first step I'm taking here is to explicitly use Http.

**As soon as I un-comment this text (and add an http import), everything breaks. I get the error `"No provider for ConnectionBackend"`**. It appears that HTTP_PROVIDERS has just stopped working as a provider.

- **How do I make this explicit use of Http work?**
- **How do I use my own CustomHttp and use the providers in HTTP_PROVIDERS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using your own `CustomHttp`, you don't need to use `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, you need to do the following (in your app.module.ts if you are using RC5 or in your main.ts if you are using RC4):

```
providers: [
    ConnectionBackend,
    provide(
        Http, {
            useFactory: (
                backend: XHRBackend,
                defaultOptions: RequestOptions) =>
                new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        }),
]
```

I had the same problem, this fixed it for me.

Edit:

You don't need to import `HTTP_PROVIDERS` if you are using RC5 because you will import `HttpModule`, but I don't exactly remember if you need `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in RC4. You will probably need it.

Comment: On Angular 2.1.1, no need for `HTTP_PROVIDERS`. Make sure to use `XHRBackend` as constructor params in your custom http class. I've written a more comprehensive guide here http://adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/

Answer (score 4):

From Angular 2.1.1 and above syntax for provide option was changed after angular2 team introduce new modules concept. Below you will find correct syntax how to add your own custom provider for Http in your **app.module.ts**

```js
export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
  return  new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions);
}

...

providers:    [
               {provide: Http, 
                         useFactory: httpFactory,
                         deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
               }
              ]
```

You can also verify the angular2 documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/XHRBackend-class.html

If you want to implement you own CustomHttp class I will recommend you to read Thierry Templier article when step by step he is introducing how to do that.

[Implementing CustomHttp for angular2](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/) this is very helpful article which is describing how to extend to intercept request calls and add custom handling errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the implementations of XHRBackend and RequestOptions you can do it simplier like:

```
providers: [
    {provide: Http, useClass: MyCustomHttp}
]
```

Comment: In my case, I have another custom provider that uses my custom Http implementation. I was having issues _no_ _end_ until I did this. Thank you very much @Serginho